# Excel: Lookup Value not recognized

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I'm performing a VLOOKUP and some cells are not returning any data even though the Lookup Value does exist in the table array. When I select the Lookup Value and hit Enter on that cell the value then displays. Has anyone experienced this issue? Is there anyway to correct this?

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP([@[NAIC Code]], Carrier[[NAIC Code]:[ICO]],3,FALSE),"CANNOT LOCATE: ENTER MANUALLY")
```

[image: Formlula Sheet]
[image: Array]

After I select the Lookup Value Cell and hit Enter:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This usually happens because the data in the lookup field (not where the VLOOKUP formula is, the data you are looking up) has been pasted in from somewhere else.

To fix it, you can click on the column header for the lookup field and click on **Text to Columns** in the data tab. Depending on the data is (numeric, text, etc) you usually can just click on the **Finish** button.

You should see all your VLOOKUPs working now.

Comment: This fixed the issue. I had to do this for more than one of my Worksheets.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes there is a bug between text and numeric data, so I just add &"" to every variable i am searching for
ex : `VLOOKUP(A1&"",B:B,...)`
Also converting all the sheet to text can help, but sometime it just doesn't work.